# Will I have enough time to make my connecting flight in Heathrow to Brussels?

Tags: lhr, short-connections, connecting-flights

Will I have enough time to make my connecting flight in Heathrow to Brussels?  My flight from the U.S. arrives in Terminal 2 at 10:10, and my scheduled flight for Brussels  leaves Terminal 2 at 11:05.

I thought this would be sufficient time when I made the separate reservations, but now I'm not so sure.

From what I'm reading, I would not have to go through U.K. Customs/Immigration. I should have my boarding pass (through online check-in) and will only have a carry-on bag (no checked luggage). Am I correct that I will only need to go through security and head to the new gate? I feel like I should be fine in theory, but perhaps I'm being naive.

Comment: This is really risky. My advice would be to NEVER make separate reservations with less then 2 hours between flights.
If the first flight delays even 5 minutes, there's a great chance you won't be able to catch the second flight...

Comment: Very risky... another flight might not cost that much more if you miss it, also check out eurostar prices, a train to Brussels might be cheaper and takes under 2 hours. Just at looking today you can fly for £151 or the cheapest eurostar today is £112. Flight would be worth the extra as you're already at the airport.

Comment: Not to mention the train is kinda cool, you see the countryside and it gets you to downtown Brussels.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have answered your own question. You have to travel from your arrival gate to the border controls (which can be a 10 minute walk from some gates at terminal 2), pass through security (which could take half an hour or more if you are unlucky), and then sprint to your gate (which, again, could be a 10 minute walk away). Bearing in mind that boarding will close probably around 20 minutes before departure, you will need to do all this in around 30 minutes. If you are *lucky* and also a fast runner you will make it there just as they are about to close boarding. I would say you have a slim chance of making it. I would bet against you. My tip is that you should rebook your flight.

I tried entering [your details](https://www.heathrow.com/flight-connections/connections-cancelled-diverted-stopover/UA940/LH5595/18-APR-2019/18-APR-2019/2/5A) into Heathrow's connection planner. They don't think you have a hope of making it, and suggest that you should contact your airline on arrival to rebook.

Comment: The OP says he has no checked baggage and can check in for his next flight online, so he doesn't need to pass through immigration. Still quite risky, though.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, you're right my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Heathrow always takes longer than you expect. It's not just a matter of "arrive in gate A, jog to gate B". Even in the same terminal and without having to go through immigration, you will have to re-clear security and go through customs. While an hour is *probably* enough, a relatively short delay in your incoming flight would be enough to screw up your travel plans, leaving you in an international terminal without an onward ticket. You do not want to be in that situation.